# NoMethodError when trying to install Middleman on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, middleman

I am currently trying to install Middleman on Mac OS X. I have already done some initial steps described here:

http://petertran.com.au/2013/02/23/how-to-install-middleman-mac-on-macosx/

But the main installation via "gem install middleman" breaks. Here is some output.

```
[..]
In file included from Variadic.c:35:
In file included from /usr/include/ffi/ffi.h:58:
/usr/include/ffi/fficonfig.h:120:9: warning: 'PACKAGE_TARNAME' macro redefined
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libffi"
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0/config.h:3:9: note: previous definition is here
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
        ^
In file included from Variadic.c:35:
In file included from /usr/include/ffi/ffi.h:58:
/usr/include/ffi/fficonfig.h:123:9: warning: 'PACKAGE_VERSION' macro redefined
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.1"
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0/config.h:4:9: note: previous definition is here
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
        ^
5 warnings generated.
cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o ffi_c.bundle AbstractMemory.o ArrayType.o Buffer.o Call.o ClosurePool.o DataConverter.o DynamicLibrary.o ffi.o Function.o FunctionInfo.o LastError.o LongDouble.o MappedType.o MemoryPointer.o MethodHandle.o Platform.o Pointer.o Struct.o StructByReference.o StructByValue.o StructLayout.o Thread.o Type.o Types.o Variadic.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby -lffi  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 ffi_c.bundle ./.gem.20130626-33730-oxkffm
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
```

Thanks for any input. I am not that good in Mac OS X compiler stuff in context with ruby binaries or whatever this ffi module is. All these warnings (and there a ton more which i havent quoted) also seem a bit strange to me.

Comment: Looks like ruby 1.8.x. Do middleman and its dependencies still support that?

Comment: Perhaps you were right. I uninstalled MacPorts and did a clean install of latest 1.9.x Ruby, reinstalled MacPorts (latest version) and did a fresh install of middleman. Now everything is fine.

Comment: I'd suggest you post that as an answer then.

Comment: you are right. Thanks. Was my first question ever here on SO

Answer (score 0):

After a hint from Denis, i did the following to resolve it:

I uninstalled MacPorts and did a clean install of latest 1.9.x Ruby, reinstalled MacPorts (latest version) and did a fresh install of middleman. Now everything is fine.